# How to center all elements in a div with Foundation

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, centering

I need to center all of the elements in a div `thresholds-container`. I'm using the CSS framework Foundation, but can't seem to figure out how to do this. I don't need them centered vertically, just all lined up horizontally within the div, and centered.

```
<div class="row" id="filters-container">
    <div class="row" id="thresholds-container">
        <h2 class="small-2 columns">Priority Thresholds:</h2>
        <span data-has-options="icon--circle" class="icon--circle circle--accent3 icon-md icon-caret_double_up small-1 columns" id="high-priority-icon"></span>
        <p class="small-2 columns" id="doh-high-priority">More than {{ dohHighPriority }} Days on Hand</p>
        <span data-has-options="icon--circle" class="icon--circle circle--brand2 icon-md icon-caret_double_down small-1 columns" id="high-priority-icon"></span>
        <p class="small-2 columns" id="doh-low-priority">Less than {{ dohLowPriority }} Days on Hand</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried assigning `margin: 0 auto` too all of the elements, and that did not work. The elements stayed in place.

I've tried assigning the `small-centered` to each element, but that centers each element and stacks them vertically.

I just want an even amount of space on the left-most and right-most element. How would I do that?

EDIT: What I wound up doing for the time being was using `offset` on the left-most element to "center" all of them, but I feel like there must be a better way.

```
<h2 class="large-2 columns large-offset-2">Priority Thresholds:</h2>
```

This technically centers everything I need it to, but I would like to know how to actually center these elements without offsetting the left-most element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [.align-spaced or .align-justify](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/flexbox-utilities.html#horizontal-alignment) depending if you want outer space or just spacing between elements.

https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/flexbox-utilities.html#horizontal-alignment

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container